Google Tag Manager/Firebase Set Up and Data Tracking Issues
I have set up Google Tag Manager and the containers within. I linked Firebase through the app to receive data however we are still not getting any data. The triggers are not firing and as we are working within a third party platform for the app, we are unable to paste the Google tracking code to set up the tags. The third party platform also can't do this for us so we have hit a wall on how to set up GTM/GA for our app.
We have worked with the third party team to set up the GTM containers. It seems we can't implement the tracking code to accurately set up the Google tags. We are unsure at this point how to move forward and receive data from our app without being able to directly implement the code. Any advice and solutions is appreciated!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
